# Maintain sorted collection in java, with index access

Tags: java

I'm looking for a collection that maintains sorted order as well as index access. My program will have hundreds of thousands of iterations, so I don't want to keep calling Collections.sort, as that would be too costly.

Comment: for a good discussion why there exists no standard JDK sorted list see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java

Comment: See this q/a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031572/sorted-array-list-in-java

Comment: You can use binary search to insert in an ArrayList while maintaining order e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3602046/1413133)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the standard collections that come with Java supports this, but you can implement your own.

One way to implement such a collection would be to use a sorted array. Index lookups are easy. Value lookups could use [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29). Inserting a new value would also use `binarySearch()` to find the insertion point, then shift the remainder of the values to make room for the new value, auto-extending the array as needed.