# ChildEventListener make wrong order when sort list

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using onChildAdded to load conversations. but it make wrong order when I try to sort ( by algorithms or Collections.sort ).

this is my code:

```
      Object_Conversation conversation=new Object_Conversation(dataSnapshot.getKey(),message);


//                            mConvers_List.add(conversation);
//                            mConvers_Adapter.notifyItemInserted(mConvers_List.size()-1);

                        if (mConvers_List.isEmpty()){

                            mConvers_List.add(conversation);
                            mConvers_Adapter.notifyItemInserted(mConvers_List.size()-1);

                        }else {

                            if (message.getSend_time_inmilies()<mConvers_List.get(0).getMessage().getSend_time_inmilies()) {

                                mConvers_List.add(conversation);
                                mConvers_Adapter.notifyItemInserted(mConvers_List.size()-1);


                            }else {

                                mConvers_List.add(0,conversation);
                                mConvers_Adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);

                            }
                        }





//                        for (int i = 0; i<mConvers_List.size(); i++){
//                            for (int j = i; j<mConvers_List.size(); j++){
//                                long time_j=mConvers_List.get(j).getMessage().getSend_time_inmilies();
//                                long time_i=mConvers_List.get(i).getMessage().getSend_time_inmilies();
//
//                                if (time_j > time_i){
//                                    Collections.swap(mConvers_List,i,j);
//                                    mConvers_Adapter.notifyItemMoved(i,j);
//                                }
//                            }
//                        }
//
//                        mConvers_Adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,mConvers_List.size());
```

and the result, this is not the true order.

[image]

Comment: May be this question help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601472/6376080

Comment: you meant , this is about the sort algorithms  ?

Comment: This about to insert new element in already sorted arraylist.

Comment: my way above : when load a new conversation, I will compare send time of this conversation with index 0 conversation to insert. we dont need to use sort algorithm